# In the opening scene, why does Hiratsuka-sensei get held up by some policemen?

Tags: oregairu

I'm talking about this scene where Hiratsuka-sensei gets held up by some policemen.

[image]
[image]

To the best of knowledge, this scene has not played out in the light novel or the anime.

What is happening in this scene?

Comment: Is that the scene from the new OP? There's only 1 question on [Yahoo! Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11144665441) that guessed she was speeding (for whatever reason), but if it's from an OP scene, then I think anything can goes...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of illegal parking at the bridge. If i remember it correctly, Hiratsuka sensei brought Hikigaya there to talk about the service club, i think it's between ep. 6-8, (because Hikigaya and Yukino had an argument/ misunderstanding) there was a sign that says parking is not allowed at the bridge.